# To get properly formatted text in table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an editable html table wherein I want following formatting possible-

1. It should save the data in new line on clicking on enter and not go on next line unless I hit enter.
2. It should hide the overflown text, if the text exceeds the width of column and show on hover.
3. Maximum three lines should be visible even if there are more lines it show hide them and show only on hover.

I have tried a lot to achieve this but nothing seems to help much and I am newbie so kindly help guys.
Here is what I have tried-

```
td {
  white-space:pre-wrap;
  max-width: 100px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: use textarea inside td

Comment: that won't help achieve me ,what i am trying to...It is already a textarea...I need help with css..@Tuhin

Comment: Is it ok for you if some javascript or jquery?

Comment: Your example already addresses points 1, and point 2 is solved simply by doing `td:hover {overflow: visible}`, so I presume the problem is with point 3? That's the problem with tds, they don't treat `height` the same as other elements. Using a textarea inside is the sanest approach.

Comment: @MrLister...My example only takes the text to a new line ,It does not solve the issue of hiding the overflown text also when my text exceeds the width if cell it moves on to new line which i don't want to happen...Also It does not solve the issue of showing only three lines by default

Comment: @Tuhin..I am ok with using jquery or javascript unless it lengthens the code or makes it complicated..